# Could not use domain name instead of static IP

Tags: networking

I'm working with some partners in the UK. My office is in Vietnam. We are having a network problem: My partner can access an internal website using the domain name, e.g. http://example.com, but I can only access that website using the direct IP, e.g. 192.168.1.85. I can not ping that web server using "ping website.name" but it works if I using "ping 192.168.1.85".

I want to use the domain name. Please help.

Comment: A specific issue like this is MUCH easier to resolve if you let us know what the actual domain and IP addresses are that you're working with, otherwise, your question might as well be "DNS isn't working, what's wrong?"  More details please.  When you ping website.name, what do you get back, an IP (and what is it) or a host not found error?

Comment: Dear Justin Scott,
Pinging the website.name will get a host not found error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add this row to the hosts file (/etc/hosts or C:\WINDOWS\System32\drivers\etc\hosts) in the client machine:

192.168.1.85 website.name

Restart the browser and try again.

This is a classic DNS problem, you should ask to you network admin to solve it in a best way!

Comment: Thank you lg,
Your suggestion is great but if the domain name changes its IP, this won't be stable :)

Comment: Yes, of course. I wrote you must solve the problem in a best way. This DNS configuration is known as Split DNS; search on internet: "split dns internal external" and find the right solution for you.

Answer (score 2):

Either DNS is not properly set up for the domain, or you are not configured to use DNS properly. What happens if you do an `nslookup website.name`? If you share more details about the domain, and about what operating system you have, we can probably give you more things to look for and instructions for checking them.

You could also try looking up the domain with a different DNS server. For example, here I'm looking up serverfault.com on google's domain server (8.8.8.8):

```
$ nslookup serverfault.com 8.8.8.8
Server:  google-public-dns-a.google.com
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    serverfault.com
Address:  69.59.196.212
```

If you try looking up your domain on another DNS server, what results do you get? For example:

```
nslookup domain.name 8.8.8.8
```

Comment: When I try "nslookup domain.name 8.8.8.8" (the domain.name is the one I used in the company) I get "*** google-public-dns-a.google.com can't find xxx: Non-existent domain" where xxx is my domain.name. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Comment: @Nam Gi VU That means that DNS is not configured properly for the domain. The fact that it works inside the office in UK indicates that they have a DNS server in that office that is configured with the domain, but it isn't configured to share that information with the rest of the world. They need to change the configuration of the DNS server so that you can look up the domain properly.